# How to convert to/from AnyPublisher<Void, Never> and AnyPublisher<Never, Never>?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm wrapping async requests in Combine publishers so they can easily be used across different pipelines.

A consumer might hold on to these publishers as follows:

```
struct Dependencies {
  var loadImageRequest: AnyPublisher<UIImage, Never>
  var saveToDatabaseRequest: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
  var saveToUserDefaultsRequest: AnyPublisher<Never, Never>
}
```

Two of the more common types of requests are:

1. **Fire and forget (complete immediately)**: For example, saving a value to User Defaults, could be modeled as a fire and forget. So far it seems like `AnyPublisher<Never, Never>` is a good way to express this type. This can easily be constructed via `Empty<Never, Never>(completeImmediately: true)`.
2. **Fire, wait, and ignore result**: An example of this is saving a value to the database (and ignoring the result), but still wanting to wait until the save is complete before continuing the pipeline. I've been using `AnyPublisher<Void, Never>` to model these request types. An easy way to construct these is via a `Future<Void, Never>() { promise in promise(.success(()))}`.

Both of these have the common theme of ignoring the result. Therefore, when handing these off to the consumers, it's sometimes useful to convert between these two data types: `AnyPublisher<Never, Never>` and `AnyPublisher<Void, Never>`.

There are three potential ways to convert between the two:

1. `Never -> Void`, complete immediately

   One way to convert this is with some forced casting:

   ```
   let neverPublisher: AnyPublisher<Never, Never> = ...
   let voidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> = neverPublisher
     .map { _ in () }
     .append(Just(()))
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   ```
2. `Void -> Never`, wait until Void completes

   Since there is a bulit-in operator for this one, the conversion is easy:

   ```
   let voidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> = ...
   let neverPublisher: AnyPublisher<Never, Never> = voidPublisher
     .ignoreOutput()
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   ```
3. `Void -> Never`, complete immediately

   I'm not sure the best way to do this conversion. The solution I came up with has two major downsides: using `handleEvents`, and needing `cancellables` defined somewhere:

   ```
   let cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
   let voidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> = ...
   let neverPublisher: AnyPublisher<Never, Never> = Empty<Never, Never>(completeImmediately: true)
     .handleEvents(receiveCompletion: { _ in voidPublisher.sink(receiveValue: { _ in }).store(in: &cancellables) })
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   ```

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to do conversion #1 (`Never -> Void`, complete immediately) without needing to invoke both `map` and `append`? (E.g. similar to how `ignoreOutput` was used to solve the second conversion?)
2. Is there a better way to do the third conversion (`Void -> Never`, complete immediately) which doesn't need `cancellables`?

Comment: Never cannot be an Output type.

Comment: @matt: that’s odd since both the `ignoreOutput()` operator and the `Empty<Never, Never>(completeImmediately: true)` publisher return an `AnyPublisher<Never, Never>` after invoking `eraseToAnyPublisher()` on iOS 13

Comment: Let me put it another way. It’s a silly thing to want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't found a more elegant way to do #2.

Here is a better #3 (`Void -> Never`, complete immediately) solution:

```
let voidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> = ...
let neverPublisher: AnyPublisher<Never, Never> = Publishers.Merge(Just<Void>(()), saveToDatabase)
  .first()
  .ignoreOutput()
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

---

And here is the [timing Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62841827/how-do-i-sleep-in-swift-playgrounds-and-get-the-latest-async-values) I used to ensure everything is functioning as expected:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

let delaySec: TimeInterval = 0.1
let halfDelaySec: TimeInterval = delaySec / 2
let halfDelayMicroSeconds: useconds_t = useconds_t(halfDelaySec * 1_000_000)
let sleepBufferMicroSeconds: useconds_t = useconds_t(0.01 * 1_000_000)

var cancellables = [AnyCancellable]()
var output: [String] = []

func performVoidAction(voidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>) {
  voidPublisher
    .handleEvents(
      receiveCompletion: { _ in output.append("performVoidAction - completion") },
      receiveCancel: { output.append("performVoidAction - cancel") })
    .sink(receiveValue: { output.append("performVoidAction - sink") })
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}

func performNeverAction(neverPublisher: AnyPublisher<Never, Never>) {
  neverPublisher
    .handleEvents(
      receiveCompletion: { _ in output.append("performNeverAction - completion") },
      receiveCancel: { output.append("performNeverAction - cancel") })
    .sink(receiveValue: { _ in output.append("performNeverAction - sink") })
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}

func makeSaveToDatabasePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
  Deferred { _saveToDatabase() }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func makeSaveToUserDefaultsPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Never, Never> {
  Deferred { _saveToUserDefaults() }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// --->(Void)|
// AnyPublisher<Void, Never> wraps an API that does something and finishes upon completion.
private func _saveToDatabase() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
  return Future<Void, Never> { promise in
    output.append("saving to database")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delaySec) {
      output.append("saved to database")
      promise(.success(()))
    }
  }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// |
// AnyPublisher<Never, Never> wraps an API that does something and completes immediately, it does not wait for completion.
private func _saveToUserDefaults() -> AnyPublisher<Never, Never> {
  output.append("saved to user defaults")
  return Empty<Never, Never>(completeImmediately: true)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func assert(_ value: Bool) -> String {
  value ? "✅" : "❌"
}

// tests
assert(output.isEmpty)

var saveToDatabase = makeSaveToDatabasePublisher()
assert(output.isEmpty, "It should not fire the action yet.")

// verify database save, first time
performVoidAction(voidPublisher: saveToDatabase)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saving to database")
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saved to database")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performVoidAction - sink")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performVoidAction - completion")
assert(output.isEmpty)

// verify database save, second time
performVoidAction(voidPublisher: saveToDatabase)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saving to database")
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saved to database")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performVoidAction - sink")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performVoidAction - completion")
assert(output.isEmpty)

var saveToUserDefaults = makeSaveToUserDefaultsPublisher()
assert(output.isEmpty, "It should not fire the action yet.")

// verify user defaults save, first time
performNeverAction(neverPublisher: saveToUserDefaults)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saved to user defaults")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performNeverAction - completion")
assert(output.isEmpty) // 'perform never action' should never be output

// verify user defaults save, second time
performNeverAction(neverPublisher: saveToUserDefaults)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saved to user defaults")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performNeverAction - completion")
assert(output.isEmpty) // 'perform never action' should never be output

// MARK: - Problem: AnyPublisher<Never, Never> -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

// MARK: Solution 1
// `|` ➡️ `(Void)|`

performVoidAction(
  voidPublisher: saveToUserDefaults
    .map { _ in () }
    .append(Just(()))
    .eraseToAnyPublisher())
assert(output.removeFirst() == "saved to user defaults")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performVoidAction - sink")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performVoidAction - completion")
assert(output.isEmpty) // 'perform never action' should never be output"


// MARK: - Problem: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> -> AnyPublisher<Never, Never>

// MARK: Solution 2 (Wait)
// `--->(Void)|` ➡️ `--->|`

performNeverAction(
  neverPublisher: saveToDatabase.ignoreOutput().eraseToAnyPublisher())
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saving to database")
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saved to database")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performNeverAction - completion")
assert(output.isEmpty)


// MARK: Solution 3 (No wait)
// `--->(Void)|` ➡️ `|`

performNeverAction(
  neverPublisher: Publishers.Merge(Just<Void>(()), saveToDatabase)
    .first()
    .ignoreOutput()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher())
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "performNeverAction - completion")
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saving to database")
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(output.isEmpty)
usleep(halfDelayMicroSeconds + sleepBufferMicroSeconds)
assert(!output.isEmpty && output.removeFirst() == "saved to database")
assert(output.isEmpty)

print("done")
```

Finally, here are the solutions as operators on Publisher:

```
extension Publisher where Output == Never {
  func asVoid() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Failure> {
    self
      .map { _ in () }
      .append(Just(()).setFailureType(to: Failure.self))
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

extension Publisher where Output == Void {
  func asNever(completeImmediately: Bool) -> AnyPublisher<Never, Failure> {
    if completeImmediately {
      return Just<Void>(())
        .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
        .merge(with: self)
        .first()
        .ignoreOutput()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
      return self
        .ignoreOutput()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
  }
}
```